# Using relative paths within SQL XQuery arithmetic

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, xquery, xquery-sql

Is there a simple way to use a relative path within XQuery arithmetic within SQL Server?

e.g. with the below code, I'm repeating `/a/b/` on both sides of the operator:

```
declare @x xml = '<a><b><x>10</x><y>20</y></b></a>'
select @x.value('((/a/b/x/text())[1] + (/a/b/y/text())[1])[1]','bigint')
```

**More Info**

NB: I'm aware that in the example above I could use the SUM function... Sadly that would not apply to my real use case, where I have multiple elements with various operations to be performed between them.

I'm also familiar with the `nodes` option to do something like below:

```
select ab.b.value('((./x)[1] + (./y)[1])[1]','bigint')
from @x.nodes('/a/b') ab(b)
```

I'm also familiar with using `outer apply`/`cross apply` to access such subqueries when the XML is coming from a column rather than a variable.  That's currently the route I'm taking, but it feels a little clunky.

I'm visualising a solution similar to this:
`select @x.value('(/a/b[(./x)[1] + (./y)[1]])[1]','bigint')`; i.e. similar to how a filter can be applied to multiple elements within the context of the current path; but haven't found how that would be written (assuming this is even possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @x xml
SET @x = '<a><b><x>10</x><y>20</y></b></a>'

select @x.query('
    for $i in /a/b
    return
        data($i/x[1]) + data($i/y[1])
')
```

If the path is too long and you want to use an "alias" for it, the above can be an option. It may look nicer a bit? You can replace + by other operators such as -, *,etc. (tested with SQL server 2005)

Answer (score 1):

In most XQuery systems, given your data, you can replace

```
'((/a/b/x/text())[1] + (/a/b/y/text())[1])[1]'
```

with

```
'/a/b/(x+y)'
```

But I believe the SQL server implementation has its own quirks so this might not apply in your case. If you need a way to get around pessimistic type checking then

```
/a/b/sum((x,y))
```

might do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Sadly the first solution gives `Msg 9341, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
XQuery [value()]: Syntax error near '(', expected a step expression.
`, and the second : `Msg 9335, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
XQuery [value()]: The XQuery syntax '/function()' is not supported.
`

Comment: Looks like it's supporting an XQuery subset that's actually closer to XPath 1.0.